# How to show changed edited lines (diff) in monaco editor without using the split mode diff editor?

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I'm trying to achieve something like this in monaco editor. Is there a way I can achieve this kind of notifying the changed lines in monaco without using DiffEditor (the one that shows in split mode?)

TIA.

[image]

I'm looking for exact experience as how vscode notifies of changed lines inline.

Answer (score 1):

Use option `renderSideBySide`

```
 <DiffEditor
     original={text1}
     modified={text2}
     options={{ renderSideBySide: false }}
     language={language}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can achieve that with the regular Editor, but the DiffEditor does allow you to show changes inline:

```js
var diffEditor = monaco.editor.createDiffEditor(document.getElementById("container"), {
    // Render the diff inline
    renderSideBySide: false
});
```

Comment: renderSideBySide false will show both removed and added lines at a time. I want it so that only a removed/added indicator shows up in the left gutter, on clicking/hovering on it, we get a detailed diff for that changed area.